# Difference between Dimension of a Linear transformation (space) and the Dimension of its Column Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

As my title suggests, what exactly is the difference? 

The Column Space of a transformation $T: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is simply the subspace which "contains" all the possible Images, right? If so, then what is the **dimension of the matrix operator** that defines the transformation? Why is it significant anyways? What information does it give us?

Any Help is Much Appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notion of "dimension of a transformation".  Could you clarify this a bit?

Comment: I mean the dimension of a matrix. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you mean "rank of a transformation" as in the dimension of the transformation's image.

If that is the case, then if you express the transformation by left multiplication with a matrix $A$, then the dimension of the columnspace of $A$ is exactly the rank of $T$. The column vector you are operating on is merely making a linear combinations of the columns of $A$.

There are several terms floating around here that are almost the same.

- rank of a linear transformation (there is no such thing as "the" columnspace or rowspace of a transformation, but the dimension of the image is well-defined.)
- column rank of a matrix (dimension of columnspace of the matrix)
- row rank of a matrix  (dimension of the rowspace of a matrix)

I think you will be able to sort it all out from [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_a_linear_transformation).